# Powershell splat destroy variable

Tags: powershell, hash, splat

The argument to `Split-Path` below is incorrect and it should have been `$delZipExe`.
This makes the `$delZipCmd` hash be set to nothing.
I would expect `WorkingDirectory` value to be set to nothing in the `$delZipCmd` hash.

Why does this happens?

```
Set-StrictMode -Version latest
$delZipExe = '\\servername\ziptools\SP3DDeliverZips.exe'
$delZipDest = "D:\"
$delZipArgs = @( '/execute',
                 '/source', '/RAD ', '/debugpdb', '/wait'
               )
$delZipCmd = @{ FilePath = $delZipExe;
                ArgumentList = $delZipArgs;
                NoNewWindow = $true;
                WorkingDirectory = (Split-Path $delZipCmd);   # <== should be $delZipExe
                Wait = $true;
              }
$delZipCmd | ft
```

Comment: I do not understand your question, what error you are getting, what you expect, nor what the comment on line 10 of your code means. Can you clarify please?

Comment: On the last line, $delZipCmd is $null. As I said in the question, I would like to understand why that happenned, since I expected that WorkingDirectory would have the value $null, but that all the other entries would be set correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since validation of the parameter argument to `Split-Path` throws a terminating error *during* construction of the hash table, the entire expression is terminated.

You can isolate the `Split-Path` statement in a subexpression (`$()`) to avoid this:

```
$delZipCmd = @{ 
    FilePath = $delZipExe;
    ArgumentList = $delZipArgs;
    NoNewWindow = $true;
    WorkingDirectory = $(Split-Path $delZipCmd);   # <== notice the $
    Wait = $true;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using $delZipCmd for Split-Path, *inside* the declaration for $delZipCmd hash table?  This code does not make sense to me.

Comment: @KoryGill Because OP specifically asks about the behavior *when he does exactly this* - please re-read the question

Comment: With strict mode, I would expect the original code to not run because $delZipCmd is not set (which is what you get when you run it from a new/clean powershell window without any prev variables set). so to me, the question asserts something in correct as a premise.  moving on...